# How to replace request header content-type?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, server, content-type

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  text/plain;


  server{
    listen 3001;
    server_name localhost;

    location /token {
      proxy_hide_header Content-Type;
      proxy_set_header Content-Type "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
   //...//
    }
  }
}
```

I send a `Content-Type: application/json` header but I want to replace it with `text/plain`. My nginx code does not work. How do I fix it?

Comment: if you want to send `text/plain` why are you sending `application/json`?

Comment: @JaromandaX I want to make all content-type to text/plain.

Comment: don't include mime.types

Comment: @JaromandaX Still not working

Comment: hmmm ... you've restarted nginx I presume - because after removing mime.types I DO get the default content type as per setting